# How to select single rows using MAX and GROUP BY on non-uniqe field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I came across this very simple case where I need to select a list of conversations from `Conversations` table along with latest message from `Messages` table - which has non-uniqe `dateCreated` field.

After long research I came up with this query:

```sql
SELECT
Conversations.id,
dateCreated,
`name`,
lastMessageId,
lastMessageDate,
lastMessagePayload
FROM Conversations
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    id AS lastMessageId,
    m1.conversationId,
    payload AS lastMessagePayload,
    m1.dateCreated AS lastMessageDate,
  FROM Messages AS m1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT conversationId, MAX(dateCreated) AS mdate FROM Messages GROUP BY conversationId
  ) AS m2
  ON m1.conversationId = m2.conversationId AND m1.dateCreated = m2.mdate
) AS msg2
ON msg2.conversationId = Conversations.id
ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
```

Query works well but if two latest messages in same conversation have exact same `dateCreated` field this query would then output two conversations with same `id` but different `lastMessage...` row of fields.

I just couldn't find a way to get around this problem as main problem is when you do GROUP BY a field and MAX on another non-uniqe field then you can't get out always only **one** row out.

Any idea how to get list of unique conversations with latest message (any message of the two if they have the same date)?

Comment: Please show example data and desired results, as well as specifying which version of MySQL?  (MySQL 8.0 has functionality that helps, but is not present in MySQL 5.x)

Comment: please share table structure with create and insert script of sample data and output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`row_number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)!

```
select c.*, m.*    -- or whatever columns you want
from conversations c left join
     (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by m.conversationid order by m.dateCreated desc, m.id desc) as seqnum
      from messages m
     ) m
     on m.conversation_id = c.id and
        m.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.x version...

Use a correlated sub-query to get the latest message id *(for a given conversation)*, using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT
  Conversations.Conversations.id,
  Conversations.dateCreated,
  Conversations.`name`,
  Messages.id                AS lastMessageId,
  Messages.payload           AS lastMessagePayload,
  Messages.dateCreated       AS lastMessageDate,
FROM
  Conversations
LEFT JOIN
  Messages
    ON Messages.id = (
        SELECT lookup.id
          FROM Messages AS lookup
         WHERE lookup.conversationId = Conversations.id
      ORDER BY lookup.dateCreated DESC
         LIMIT 1
    )
ORDER BY
  Conversations.dateCreated DESC
```

In the event of two messages having the same date, the message you get is non-deterministic / arbitrary.

You could, if you wanted, therefore change it to get the highest id from the most recent date...

```
      ORDER BY lookup.dateCreated DESC, lookup.id DESC
         LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This looks promising, a bit busy at the moment, but will give it a try soon.